# Why is it called "Font Lock" mode?

Tags: font-lock, emacs-history

Just wondering, because ...

1. The function of [`font-lock-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html) is to programmatically un/assign a given [typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface) or [typeface font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font) to text. But it's just an assignment, which can be easily overridden; FLM doesn't `lock` in any sense of that verb that's reasonable to me. (Am I missing something?)
2. When I'm `org-mode`ing, I regularly toggle `M-x font-lock-mode` to either *(a)* hide the Org magic (e.g., inspect the underlying Org markup/syntax, search for URLs inside hyperlinks), or *(b)* "magic on" (i.e., reprettify the display). But I don't work with Org every day, and if it's been awhile I find myself needing to research "what's the name of that `<pig-latin>` mucking fode `</pig-latin>` I need to call?"

So I'm hoping my life will be easier if I know `font lock`'s etymology ... plus I'm curious.

Comment: I kinda doubt anyone has a definitive answer for this. But because its highlighting is applied automatically (by the mode) and defined by rules, it stays in effect, unlike some other kinds of highlighting. It's locked/attached to given syntactic elements. That would be my guess, but hopefully someone will have a real answer.

Comment: I also don't know, but I think of it as analogous to "caps lock" -- while the mode is enabled, special font behaviours are in effect.  I have a feeling that I once saw a Q&A with jwz where this question was answered, but I can't find it, and don't recall whether it actually aligns with my suggestion.